# What's the pyspark directory location in cloudera

Tags: pyspark

I am not able to get the python directory in cloudera VM
Can anyone please tell me the default pyspark directory in cloudera ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you not just echo $SPARK_HOME from a console

Comment: Showing nothing

Answer (score 0):

You can find spark home directory under `/usr/lib/spark` , under this in `bin` you can find pyspark or spark-shell.